# getting the content of $vars array in elgg

Tags: elgg

I tried reading the content of the $vars array I passed to the layout of my elgg theme,but it returns an empty string i.e $vars['content']==="",but I succeed to extract the title of the page $vars['title'],when I print_r $vars I noticed 'content' was in the array body ,I tried $vars['body']['content'] yet nothing ,also the css and js extended do not load for the header and footer;
thanks.
My elgg version is 1.11
Here is the code
In start.php

```
elgg_register_page_handler('mutumbu','page_success_register_init');

//page handler
function page_success_register_init($segments){
    if($segement[0] == 'welcome'){
   $params = array('content'=>'<h1>hello world</h1>');  

   $body = elgg_view_layout('mutumbu_main',$params);

   echo elgg_view_page('welcome',$body);

}
}
```

In mutumbu_main layout found /mod//views/default/page/layouts/mutumbu_main.php

```
<?php echo $vars['content'] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code:

```
$segement[0]
```

Surely you mean

```
$segments[0]
```